# Rake task not running

Tags: ruby, jruby, rake-task

Every time I call my rake task it say:

```
[2012-07-12 15:50:01] ERROR IOError: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:324:in `_write_data'
        C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:180:in `send_header'
        C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpresponse.rb:103:in `send_response'
        C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:79:in `run'
        C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
        C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
[2012-07-12 15:50:29] ERROR IOError: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:55:in `run'
        C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
        C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
```

I have tryed different options thinking that it could be the call to the rake task but apparently isn't, also I have tryed with Mongrel and WEBRick in case that it could be the server.
I'm using Jruby 1.3.1

**The task it's not been executed.**

This is part of my code:

```
application_controller.rb

 def call_rake(task, options = {})
    options[:rails_env] ||= Rails.env
    args = options.map { |n, v| "#{n.to_s.upcase}='#{v}'" }
    system "C:/jruby-1.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')} start"
  end

forbidden_file.rake

desc "Process CSV file"
task :process_file => :environment do
  forbidden_file = ForbiddenFile.find(ENV["csv"])
  forbidden_file.upload_file
end
```

Controller

```
...
call_rake :process_file, :csv => params[:files]
redirect_to forbidden_files_url
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now, I just removed the word `start` from the command.

```
system "rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')}"
```